Next button displayed instead of Done button on keyboard
I tried to change some part of the keyboard via imeAction, but I can still see that this only applies to the first textfield:

How can I solve this problem?
@Composable
fun TipTimeLayout() {
    EditNumberField(
        label = R.string.bill_amount,
        value = amountInput,
        onValueChange = { amountInput = it },
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
        ),
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(bottom = 32.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
    )
    EditNumberField(
        value = tipInput,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Done,
        ),
        onValueChange = { tipInput = it },
        label = R.string.how_was_the_service,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(top = 32.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth(),
    )
}

/**
 * Calculates the tip based on the user input and format the tip amount
 * according to the local currency.
 * Example would be "$10.00".
 */
private fun calculateTip(amount: Double, tipPercent: Double = 15.0): String {
    val tip = tipPercent / 100 * amount
    return NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(tip)
}

@Composable
fun EditNumberField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    @StringRes label: Int,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        modifier = Modifier,
        label = { Text(stringResource(label)) },
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
            keyboardType = KeyboardType.Number,
            imeAction = ImeAction.Next,
        ),
    )
}

When the user taps the second text field, a Done button should appear in the lower right corner of the keyboard.

In your EditNumberField composable you explicitly set imeAction = ImeAction.Next, so both TextFields have the Next action.
You provide a keyboardOptions parameter for that composable where you set the action to Next for the first TextField and to Done for the second, but that parameter is never used, so it doesn't matter what you set that to.

The problem in your code seems to be in EditNumberField composable, instead of creating a new KeyboardOptions with ImeAction.Next it should use the one provided by parameter:
@Composable
fun EditNumberField(
    value: String,
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit,
    @StringRes label: Int,
    keyboardOptions: KeyboardOptions,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    TextField(
        value = value,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        modifier = Modifier,
        label = { Text(stringResource(label))},
        singleLine = true,
        keyboardOptions = keyboardOptions,
    )
}

